# Responsive layout with innerwidth and sidebars (tailwind)

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have three sidebars that toggle open/close and one main page. Like this:

[image]

- the sidebars can be open or closed (the width percentages are in the image)
- the main page width is depending on whether the sidebars are open or closed
- each of the sidebars can be independently open or closed

Here code:

```
<html lang="en">
      <head>
        ...
      </head>
      <body className="flex flex-row justify-start">
        <Sidebar-one />
        <Sidebar-two />
        <div className="flex-1 border-2 border-black">
          <main>{children}</main>
          <Footer />
        </div>
        <Sidebar />
      </body>
    </html>
```

The footer for example has responsive design:

```
      <div className="grid grid-cols-4">
        <div className="col-span-4 md:col-span-2 lg:col-span-1">
          Lorem ipsum
        </div>
        <div className="col-span-4 md:col-span-2 lg:col-span-1">
          Lorem ipsum
        </div>
        <div className="col-span-4 md:col-span-2 lg:col-span-1">
          Lorem ipsum
        </div>
        <div className="col-span-4 md:col-span-2 lg:col-span-1">
          Lorem ipsum
        </div>
      </div>
```

So when the device screen size is mobile size, then we get 1 column, for tablet screen size we get 2 columns (provided all sidebars are closed), all good. But when all sidebars are open then the `main` screen has the same width as a mobile device screen and then the responsive settings do NOT work. It seems it has to do with `innerwidth` what I am after. I tried with template literals and `classnames` but didnt get it to work (`${window.innerwidth === [30%] ? '' : ''}`, got stuck to be honest. Not sure if I am on the right track to solve like that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using [container queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_container_queries) via the [official container queries Tailwind plugin](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-container-queries). This would allow you to apply CSS with respect to an *element*'s size, rather than the *viewport* size (adjust variants to taste):

```html
<div className="grid grid-cols-4 @container">
  <div className="col-span-4 @md:col-span-2 @4xl:col-span-1">
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
  <div className="col-span-4 @md:col-span-2 @4xl:col-span-1">
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
  <div className="col-span-4 @md:col-span-2 @4xl:col-span-1">
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
  <div className="col-span-4 @md:col-span-2 @4xl:col-span-1">
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: fantastic, thank you! In the documentation it says that you can use "arbitrary value" for the sizes. But percentages do not seem to work... so @[20%]:col-span-1` does not work. Am I wrong?